# why position of n = int() (outside and inside of def)matters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

```
n = int()

def Num_to_MorseCode(n):
    if n >= 0 and n < 5:
        return '*'*n + '_'*(5-n)
    elif n < 10 and n >= 5:
        return '_'*(n-5) + '*'*(10-n)


num = input("Enter num: ")
if len(num) == 3:
    print(Num_to_MorseCode(int(num[0])), Num_to_MorseCode(int(num[1])), Num_to_MorseCode(int(num[2])))
else:
    print('error/num != 3 digit number!')
```

when  n = int() is in def output is _____ _____ _____ always and when its outside of it it works as I intended

Comment: n=int() is equivalent to n=0. When placed inside the function it resets the parameter n. Remove n=int() entirely, you don’t need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because as you call multiple time the function `Num_to_MorseCode`, if your `n = int()` is inside your function, it will reset the `num` every time you call the function, and not if you declare it outside. That is why.